# jquery dropdown problem after ajax call data

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-ui

Wondering why dropdown button not working after second dropdown generated and so on, please help. Thanks

```
$(document).on('click','.closeproductbox',function() {
    $(this).closest(".productbox").empty();
});
```

i known that its about Event Delegation problem in the following function but i am confused on why would the close button work but not the dropdown ?

```
    $('.dropdown').on('click', 'button', (function () {
        $(".btn-group").find($("ul.type")).empty();
        $("ul.type").append(loadlist());
    }));

    $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a ', (function(){
    console.log('hre');
      $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
      $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
    }));

    $("#addproductbox").click(function(){
        $("#product_detail").append(genProduct());
    });

    function loadlist() {
        var ajax_call_data = '<li><a  data-value="action one">one</a></li><li><a  data-value="action two">two</a></li<li><a  data-value="action three">three</a></li';
        return ajax_call_data;
    }

        function genProduct() {
        var code = '';
        code = '<div class="productbox">';
        code += '<div class="clbox"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default closeproductbox" aria-label="Left Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div><div class="input-group input-group-lg"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Type:</span><div class="input-group-btn dropdown"><div class="btn-group dropup"><button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span>Please select</span> <span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu type" role="menu"></ul></div></div></div>';
        code += '</div><br>';
        return code;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <div id="product_detail">
    <div class="productbox">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Type:</span>
    <div class="input-group-btn dropdown">
    <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle type productval" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span>- Please select -</span> <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu type" role="menu">
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div><br>
    </div>
    <button id="addproductbox" class="btn btn-default pull-left">+ add more</button>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: sample http://jsfiddle.net/KCHKY/qa12w69k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("#addproductbox").click(function(){
    $("#product_detail").append(genProduct());
    $("ul.type").append(loadlist());
});
```

Comment: it works on load ajax data, thanks for your solution. But still the dropdown menu won't show the value on the button after i chose.
i have read the document of Event Delegation, isn't it .on('click', 'li a ') function is already handled the new elements after the DOM ready?
Furthermore, my close box button are working ok, they are new elements after DOM too, it makes me more confuse on it, please kindly advice. Thanks!